# OPC UA Connection refused

Tags: java, opc-ua

I am trying to connect my application to the Opc ua Server

but I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect because of error: Connection refused  
com.mendix.systemwideinterfaces.MendixRuntimeException: com.mendix.core.CoreException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaException: status=Bad_ConnectionRejected, message=io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused:
```

it's my first time to deal with opc ua ,so I don't know what is the foucs of this problem.

fire wall checking and kepserver checking

Answer (score 2):

> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused:

You omitted part of the exception message, but this is a networking problem, it doesn't have anything to do with OPC UA yet.